# How to change date format django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, datetime-format

I am new to django, and I want to change date format from 2022-01-01 00:00:00 to 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.
the code that I am using is:

```
  start_date=datetime.strptime(room["available_from_date"], '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Is room["available_from_date"] in the format you want?

Comment: datetime.strftime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'). see - https://strftime.org/